# Javascript Draw pattern

Tags: javascript, logic, draw

I need some function to return pattern like this :

```
= * = * =
* = * = *
= * = * =
* = * = *
= * = * =
```

i try this but i cant get it:

```
function cetakGambar(angka){
    let result = ''
    for(let i=0; i<=angka; i++){
        for(let j=0; j<=i; j++){
            result += '= '
        }
        for(let k=0; k == i; k++){
            result += ' *'
        }
        result += '\n'
    }
    return result
}

console.log(cetakGambar(5))
```

what looping i need to get that pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an ES6 solution w/o explicit iteration. It is not particularly concise and probably not too useful in this case but fun (IMHO), so I wanted to share it.

It uses `Array.from` to apply a generator function yielding the next symbol (`*` or `=`) for each cell and concats cells with spaces and rows with newlines.

```
// Utility to apply function <fn> <n> times.
function times(n, fn) {
  return Array.from({ length: n }, fn);
}

// Generator function yielding the next symbol to be drawn.
//
function cetakGambar(angka) {
  let generator = (function*() {
    let [i, s1, s2] = [0, "*", "="];
    while (true) {
      // Make sure to start a new line with a different symbol for
      // even rows in case <angka> is even
      if (i++ % angka === 0 && angka % 2 === 0) {
        [s1, s2] = [s2, s1];
      }
      // limit the generator to the number of values we actually need
      if (i === angka * angka + 1) return;

      yield i % 2 === 0 ? s1 : s2;
    }
  })();

  return times(
    angka,
    () => times(angka, () => generator.next().value).join(" ") // join symbols w/ spaces ...
  ).join("\n"); // ... and lines w/ newline
}

console.log(cetakGambar(5));
```

Codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-http-mfxgo?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track with the two nested loops. Here's an example small modification to solve the problem:

```
function cetakGambar(angka){
    let result = ''
    for(let i = 0; i < angka; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < angka; ++j) {
            result += ((i + j) % 2 == 0) ? '= ' : '* ';
        }
        result += '\n';
    }
    return result
}
```

For each `i` a row is generated by looping over `j`. For each `j` we append either an `=`  or `*` , depending on if after adding `i` and `j` the result is divisible by two (to create the alternating pattern). After each line a `\n` (newline) is appended.

Comment: One loop would be enough. `=` is always at a non-even spot and `*` on an even spot. Iterate from 1 to 25 and print the corresponding character, and after every fifth element add a newline.

Comment: Yes, although really any nested loop like this could be flattened.

Answer (score 1):

Different approach using one loop

```js
function gen(row,col){
  var i = 0;
  var out="";
  do {
   if(i%col==0) out+="\n"
   out += (i % 2) == 0 ? ' = ' : ' * ';
    i++;
  }
  while (i < row*col);
  return out;
}
 
console.log(gen(5,5));
```